# Making 5-7 l of beer in a 30l bucket

Tags: fermentation

I would like to make a small quantity of beer, using something like this

http://hbd.org/uchima/tech/extract.html

What are the downsides of using a bucket much bigger than the amount of beer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headspace won't be an issue since your beer will produce co2. I recently did 2 gallons in an eight gallon bucket and one issue I did encounter is that it felt like since the beer was so shallow in the bucket, I had a small zone from which I could rack. Otherwise, for primary, you shouldn't have a lot of problems.